# Examples of homeomorphic spaces

Tags: general-topology

Are the following pairs of spaces homeomorphic?

> (i) $\mathbb Q \cup (0, 1)$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ (as subspaces of $(\mathbb R, \tau_{usual}))$;

> (ii) $(\mathbb C, \tau_{disc})$ and $(\mathbb C, \tau_{cocountable})$;

> (iii) a circle with one point removed (in $\mathbb R^2$ with $\tau_{usual}$) and $(\mathbb R, \tau_{usual})$;

> (iv) $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these, and $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these.

The following have answers

> (v) $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable}), \ (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$

> (vi) $\mathbb R^2$ and the surface of a sphere with one point removed (natural metric
> topologies here)

> (vii) $(\mathbb Q,l_x), (\mathbb Q, l_y)$, where $x, y$ are two distinct rational numbers and $l_p$ is included-point topology

Book's answers to (v) and (vii):

> (v) No. The statement ‘there is a countably infinite closed subset’ is
> (obviously) a homeomorphic invariant, is true in $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$ and is false in $(\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$

> (vii) Yes. The map $h : \mathbb Q → \mathbb Q$ given by $h(x) = y, h(y) = x, h(z) = z$
> when $z \ne x$ or $y$ is routinely checkable to be a homeomorphism.

**My answers/questions regarding question above**:

(i) $\mathbb Q, (0, 1)$  are not compact and so their union is not compact meaning there's no continuous inverse function from $\mathbb Q \cup (0, 1)$

(ii) Any function from a discrete space to an indiscrete space is continuous. Since idenity $i$ is continuous and bijective, $i$ should work here to show homeomorphism

(iii) I think this is a special case of [Stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)

(iv) Any inverse image of an open set in $\mathbb N$ is a union of $2$-sets. Since the given $2$-sets are open, their union is open as well. This works in both directions, so a continuous function with its continuous inverse likely exists. I am not sure how to find a concrete homeomorphism, but would $f(x, y) = (x, y – 1)$ if $y$ is odd and $f(x, y) = (x + 1, y)$ if $x$ is even work?

Are my answers to (i) through (iv) correct? If not (or if incomplete), how do I improve them?

(v) This question might be trivial, but I am still new to the very basics of topology. Consider $f: (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite}) \to (\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$. Every $Y \in (\mathbb R, \tau_{cocountable})$ must have a pre-image $X \in (\mathbb R, \tau_{cofinite})$. By definition, every $X$ is open, but for $f$ to be continuous $X$ must be cocountable. Correct?

(vi) It's yet another special case of Stereographic projection. Correct?

(vii) Is $h(y)$ a typo? Did they mean $h^{-1}(y)?$

Thanks.

Edit:

Answer to (vi)

[image]

edit: I am done with the thread, but I request the thread not be deleted as there's a lot of good info in here I couldn't find elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union of two non-compact spaces can be compact. See $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$. Thus, your answer to $(i)$ needs to be redone (even if that logic held, not sure how that implies the continuous inverse thing).

For $(ii)$, remember that homeomorphisms must be continuous in both directions. Proving continuity in one direction isn't sufficient.

Your argument for $(iii)$ is just a guess. That's not sufficient.

Your argument for $(iv)$ doesn't make any sense to me at all. Find an explicit homeomorphism and prove that it is one (this shouldn't be too hard).

Your argument for $f$ in $(v)$ assumes that $f$ is the inclusion map. It doesn't have to be. You have to prove that any $f$ is not a homeomorphism, not just the inclusion map.

$(vi)$ has the same issue as $(iii)$.

There is no typo in the solution to $(vii)$.

**Conclusion**: Everything needs a major revamp here.

Comment: I think $\tau_{\text{disc}}$ in (ii) means "discrete" (as opposed to the topology generated by discs, which is what I originally thought).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Fair, I'll edit

Comment: I have an answer for (vi) so in this case, all I'd like to know is if (iii) and (vi) are special cases. Are they? Thanks.

Comment: @user947160 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DonThousand, Here's an answer for (vi): https://ibb.co/4NjRW3C I am assuming an answer to (iii) will be a special case of an answer to (vi). Either way, do we call the technique used to solve (vi), and possibly (iii), stereographic projection?

Comment: @DonThousand, to your question about (i), consider the following theorem https://ibb.co/Pt7QdH9 Does it solve (i) if $\mathbb Q \cap (0, 1)$ happen to be non-compact?

Comment: @user947160 For $(i)$, no, that doesn't work, since neither set is compact.

Comment: For $(vi)$, while the map is indeed a homeomorphism, you haven't showed it. You kind just handwaved. But yes, the same technique should work for $(iii)$, and can be called stereographic projection.

Comment: @DonThousand, isn't this linked theorem https://ibb.co/Pt7QdH9 saying no inverse function from $\mathbb Q \cap (0, 1)$ can be continuous given $\mathbb Q \cap (0, 1)$ is not compact?

Comment: @user947160 No, that's the inverse of the statement.

Comment: @DonThousand, how about arguing there's no bijection between the rationals $\mathbb Q \cap (0, 1)$ and an irrationals $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ as the former is countable and the latter is uncountable?

Comment: @user947160 That works!

Comment: @DonThousand, I think I see where my mistake in (iv) is: the function must be from naturals to naturals, not from topology on naturals to topology on naturals. In that case, the following theorem https://ibb.co/dpCGS9k should work for both (ii) and (iv) meaning identity is bijective and continuous on both naturals and complex numbers whatever the topology. (I mean $i: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is continuous in either direction). Correct?

Comment: No. That only works if the map is an automorphism (same domain/codomain). Think a bit deeper about things. An argument should pass the sniff test (and this argument should seem fishy to you).

Comment: @DonThousand, Aren't the domain and codomain in (ii) same? Are they different because of their topologies?

Comment: Precisely right.

Comment: @DonThousand, as regarding (ii), suppose $X$ is $\tau_{cocountable}$-closed. Then $\mathbb C \setminus X$ is open meaning it's in $\tau_{cocountable}$ and so $\mathbb C\setminus(\mathbb C \setminus X) = X$ is countable. Since every element in $\tau_{discrete}$ is countable $f^{-1}(X)$ must be $\tau_{discrete}$-closed. This shows $f$ is continuous. But $f^{-1}$ is also continuous as any function from discrete to non discrete space is continuous. Is that correct? If so, is identity enough to show bijection?

Answer (score 2):

As to (i): note that $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ contains no connected subset of size more than $1$. The first set has the connected and uncountable $(0,1)$ as a subspace. Not homeomorphic.

(ii): the co-countable topology on $\Bbb C$ is not Hausdorff, and the discrete topology *is*. So not homeomorphic too.

(iii): indeed a stereographic projection (2D-version) works as a homeomorphism.

(iv): the renaming of points needed is quite obvious: $1\to 1, 2 \to 3, 3 \to 2, 4 \to 4$ etc. You need to specify a map $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, *not* a map of pairs.

(v) just note that "$C$ countably infinite $\implies$ $C$ is closed" is a statement preserved by homeomorphisms (only defined in set theory terms and open/closed sets), so if one space obeys it, so does any homeomorphic space. It holds in the coountable topology but not in the cofinite topology.

(vi) is indeed a higher dimensional version of stereographic projection.

(vii) $h$ is a map that just switches the special points and leaves the rest untouched; so it's a bijection. Continuity and openness is quite clear: $O$ open in the domain (and non-empty) means it contains the spcial point, its image set then also contains te special point and is open. Same arguments for continuity.

Comment: As regards (ii), the open sets in $\tau_{cc}$ are uncountable, so the closed ones must be countably infinite whereas the open sets in $\tau_{discrete}$ are countable. Does that mean the closed sets in $\tau_{discrete}$ are uncountable meaning there's no homeo between these spaces? Thanks.

Comment: @user947160 in the discrete topology **all** sets are closed and the cocountable one only $X$ and the countable sets. Hence the difference.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, See if I understand you. Every $X$ in discrete topology is open and so $Y = \mathbb N \setminus X$ is closed. But $Y \subseteq \mathbb N$ and so $Y \in \tau_{discrete}$ meaning $Y$ is also open. That's why everything in $\tau_{discrete}$ is both open and closed. Do we call the fact that everything in $\tau_{discrete}$ is closed a "homeomorphic invariant"?

Comment: @user947160 you can call it a homeomorphism invariant or a characterisation of the discrete topology. It will certainly be preserved by any homeomorphism.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, Is my understanding of the fact that every set in discrete topology is closed correct? In (iv) renaming is bijective, but how do we show continuity? Would the following work? Let X be in the given topology of the codomain. Then $f^{-1}(X)$ is just a rearragement of $X$ and so $f^{-1}(X) $ is open?

Comment: @user947160 Yes, all complements are open etc. If $h: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $X$ obeys the property, then if $A \subseteq Y$ is countable then $h^{-1}[A]$ is countable, hence closed and so $A = h[h^{-1}[A]]$ is thus also closed (as $h$ is closed). Similarly if $Y$ obeys the property, then so does $X$: if $A\subseteq X$ is countable, then $h[A]$ is countable hence closed and then $A=h^{-1}[h[A]]$ is closed by continuity. Etc

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, does the argument in your last post refer to problem (vii) with included point topology? Sorry, I am not clear on that one.

Comment: @user947160 yes, it does. I thought that was clear.